# YUI datatable bad sorting

Tags: php, yui, yui-datatable

Again i have this path

http://www.tampografica.com/atech/admin/YUIdatatable.html

try to order by visits, its ordering by string no number... if you check the Javascript it shows that i put the number formatter

any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data reaching the table are numeric strings.  just add { key: 'someField', parser: 'number' } to the appropriate fields in the responseSchema.fields.

You can also find answers to questions like this in the YUILibrary.com forums archive: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=90